# Get the List of Multiple Element with Same ClassName

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, getelementsbyclassname

I'd like to crawl every case whose Panel Reoport has already composed from the WTO official page.

[image]

and

[image]

As you can check at the above image (or refer to

https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/dispu_e/dispu_status_e.htm,

Every case is indexed with "DS XXX" and right at the below it denotes whether the "Panel Composed" or still yet "in Consultation".

If I inspect, they all share the same

```
<p class = "panel-text-simple">
```

So I had tried following two commands:

```
elem_info = driver.find_element_by_class_name("panel-title-simple")     
elem_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='panel-title-simple']");
```

but every one of them only gives me the top most case, the most recent one.

I have to locate every case's  info, then should make a for-loop to check whether the panel composed or not.

How could I do that?

Comment: 3 Counter Questions : 1) Why was the status **PANEL ESTABLISHED, BUT NOT YET COMPOSED** ignored in your Question? 2) Why do you want a for loop `to locate every case's info` when you only want to check **panel composed or not**? 3) How do you want us to interpret the status **PANEL ESTABLISHED, BUT NOT YET COMPOSED**?

Comment: Because my final goal is to find the case where the panel body already published the Panel "Report". Panel established, not yet composed means it doesn't published the report yet.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/7plh67/anyone_interested_in_autogeneration_of_wto_panel/

Comment: this is what I about to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [find_elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) (note the 's'). This returns a list that you can then loop through:

```
documents = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("panel-title-simple");
for document in documents
    # continue with your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath below to get all the `LI`s that have a current status of 'Panel composed'

```
//li[.//p[contains(.,'Panel composed')]]
```

From there you can get the DS number

```
.//small
```

or the details

```
./p
```

and so on.